# Javascript not changing styles in CSS cheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

sorry if this is very simple but I am very new to programming.

The rest of my code is working fine, but I am trying to add a button which is hidden unless a certain element is added.

The code I have so far is this:

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="setRace(); setSubRace()">Reroll Race</button>
    <p id="race"></p>
    <button id="rerollSubrace" onclick="setSubRace()">Reroll Subrace</button>
    <p id="subrace"></p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#rerollSubrace {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
      let showSubButton = document.getElementById("rerollSubrace").style.display = "inline";

...

      function setSubRace() {
      
          if (globalRace === "Aasimar") {
              aasSubRace();
              showSubButton;
```

The function continues for all options, and everything else in the setSubRace function works absolutely fine, the button just does not display.

Any advice would be great! Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: does globalRace is equals to Aasimar? you should post a complete example of your code to get help with it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you declare your function showSubButton.
Thy the syntax ()=>{} instead.

```
 let  showSubButton = () => {document.getElementById("rerollSubrace").style.display = "inline";}
```

[Here is a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbqhrzLp/3/)

Otherwise your statement is being always executed, setting the style to "inline".

Comment: Oh this works! Thank you! It's always the simple solutions that I seem to overlook.

An extra thanks for introducing me to JS fiddle, I haven't seen it before and looks super helpful.